# Get the address of a deployed contract with etherjs

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, ethers.js

I am trying to deploy a contract from within another contract.

```
function createCollection(string memory _name, string memory _tokenName) external returns(address nftAddress)
{
    
    return address(new NFT(_name, _tokenName));
}
```

When I call this function with etherjs on the frontend I get an object back with parameters like txhash, from, to and so on. How can I get back just the address of the newly deployed contract?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the contractAddress value from the response.

[image]

Comment: This returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Not sure what version of Solidity / how you've implemented tested it & it works. Share your code if you want a review.

Added image to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of NFT factory contract that returns the address of a newest deployed NFT:

```
event SaleDeployed(address, address);

    function deployCollection(
        string memory nftName,
        string memory nftSymbol,
        string memory baseTokenURI,
        address _royaltyRecipient,
        bool _random
    ) public canDeployCollection(msg.sender) returns (address collection) {
        NFT nft = new NFT(
            nftName,
            nftSymbol,
            baseTokenURI,
            _royaltyRecipient,
            _random
        );
        //admin of the sale is the deployer of this contract
        nft.initialize(owner);
        nftCollections.push(nft);
        collectionsCreatedByUser[msg.sender].push(address(nft));
        emit CollectionDeployed(msg.sender, address(nft));
        return address(nft);
    }
```

With this test you can verify the address of the new collection by listening to the `SalesDeployed` event:

```
  context("newCollection", async () => {
    it("Should return an address", async function () {
      const _nft_name = "testname";
      const _nft_symbol = "testsymbol";
      const _base_token_uri = "testbaseuri";
      const _royaltyRecipient = "0x3d337D74851fdE1965e797521f2eE299549c2349";
      const _random = true;

    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545/')


    const tx = await Factory.deployCollection(
      _nft_name,
      _nft_symbol,
      _base_token_uri,
      _royaltyRecipient,
      _random
    );

          const rc = await tx.wait()
          const event = rc.events.find(event => event.event === 'CollectionDeployed')
          const [deployer, contractAddress] = event.args
          
          console.log(deployer, contractAddress, 'deployer & contractAddress')

          const MintUpNFT = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, NFTABI.abi, provider)
          const name = await MintUpNFT.name()
          const symbol = await MintUpNFT.symbol()
          expect(name).to.equal(_nft_name)
          expect(symbol).to.equal(_nft_symbol)
  })
})
```